# Using ORDER BY to pair values in SQL ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to use ORDER BY in a query that uses UNION.

The query returns the following:

| CRN | Inv_1 | Inv_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| GBP | -100 | -100 |
| GBP | -400 | -400 |
| GBP | -500 | -500 |
| GBP | -700 | -700 |
| GBP | -800 | -800 |
| GBP | -10000 | -10000 |
| GBP | 100 | 100 |
| GBP | 400 | 400 |
| GBP | 500 | 500 |
| GBP | 700 | 700 |
| GBP | 800 | 800 |
| GBP | 10000 | 10000 |

**Expected Output:**

| CRN | Inv_1 | Inv_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| GBP | 100 | 100 |
| GBP | -100 | -100 |
| GBP | 400 | 400 |
| GBP | -400 | -400 |
| GBP | 500 | 500 |
| GBP | -500 | -500 |
| GBP | 700 | 700 |
| GBP | -700 | -700 |

I don't have an ID to select and order by it and even if I have, I can't use it since it will appear in the table which I can't include in the month-end report.

These values will keep changing so they can't be hard coded to use case statements in order.
I tried so many options such as:

```
 ORDER BY Inv_1 DESC, Inv_1 ASC
 ORDER BY Inv_1 ASC, Inv_1 DESC
 ORDER BY Inv_1 ASC, Inv_2 DESC
 ORDER BY Inv_1 DESC, Inv_2 DESC
```

If I use **`ABS(Inv_1 DESC), Inv_1`** . This throws an error: ORDER BY ITEM MUST BE THE NUMBER OF A SELEC-LIST EXPRESSION.
I'm not using ABS but *-1 instead, since ABS returns the wrong Inv_1/Inv_2

Example:

**Using ABS with UNION doesn't work : error: ORDER BY ITEM MUST BE THE NUMBER OF A SELEC-LIST EXPRESSION. **

```
select CRN,inv_1,inv_2 from Acc UNION select CRN,inv_1,inv_2 from Acc ORDER BY CRN, ABS(inv_1),inv_1 DESC;
```

Comment: What about `order by abs(inv_1), inv_1 desc`?

Comment: didn't work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't post your query, but - this kind of works for me.

Sample data:

```
SQL> select * from test;

CRN      INV_1      INV_2
--- ---------- ----------
GBP       -700       -700
GBP        100        100
GBP        700        700
GBP       -100       -100
GBP       -500        500
GBP        400        400
GBP        500        500
GBP       -400       -400

8 rows selected.
```

Query with `order by` clause:

```
SQL> select *
  2  from test
  3  order by crn, abs(inv_1), inv_1 desc;

CRN      INV_1      INV_2
--- ---------- ----------
GBP        100        100
GBP       -100       -100
GBP        400        400
GBP       -400       -400
GBP        500        500
GBP       -500        500
GBP        700        700
GBP       -700       -700

8 rows selected.

SQL>
```

---

**[EDIT]**

Aha, now I understand (although you still didn't post your query).

If there are two tables which return the result set:

```
SQL> select * from test;

CRN      INV_1      INV_2
--- ---------- ----------
GBP       -700       -700
GBP        100        100
GBP        700        700
GBP       -100       -100

SQL> select * from test2;

CRN      INV_1      INV_2
--- ---------- ----------
GBP       -500        500
GBP        400        400
GBP        500        500
GBP       -400       -400

SQL>
```

Then - if you `UNION` them and apply `order by` *something* that isn't part of the query - it won't work:

```
SQL> select crn, inv_1, inv_2
  2  from test
  3  union
  4  select crn, inv_1, inv_2
  5  from test2
  6  order by crn, abs(inv_1), inv_1 desc;
order by crn, abs(inv_1), inv_1 desc
              *
ERROR at line 6:
ORA-01785: ORDER BY item must be the number of a SELECT-list expression


SQL>
```

What can you do? Obviously, add `abs(inv_1)` into the query:

```
SQL> select crn, inv_1, inv_2, abs(inv_1) abs_inv1
  2  from test
  3  union
  4  select crn, inv_1, inv_2, abs(inv_1) abs_inv1
  5  from test2
  6  order by crn, abs_inv1, inv_1 desc;

CRN      INV_1      INV_2   ABS_INV1
--- ---------- ---------- ----------
GBP        100        100        100
GBP       -100       -100        100
GBP        400        400        400
GBP       -400       -400        400
GBP        500        500        500
GBP       -500        500        500
GBP        700        700        700
GBP       -700       -700        700

8 rows selected.

SQL>
```

This *works*, but - now you have additional column which you don't really want in the output.

Workaround is to use a CTE or a subquery which contains `UNION`, but then - in the outer query - you can sort by `abs` value:

```
SQL> with temp as
  2    (select crn, inv_1, inv_2
  3     from test
  4     union
  5     select crn, inv_1, inv_2
  6     from test2
  7    )
  8  select crn, inv_1, inv_2
  9  from temp
 10  order by crn, abs(inv_1), inv_1 desc;

CRN      INV_1      INV_2
--- ---------- ----------
GBP        100        100
GBP       -100       -100
GBP        400        400
GBP       -400       -400
GBP        500        500
GBP       -500        500
GBP        700        700
GBP       -700       -700

8 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks but ABS doesn't work with UNION. it's throwing this error: ORDER BY ITEM MUST BE THE NUMBER OF A SELEC-LIST EXPRESSION.

Comment: Aha; I think I got it. Have a look at edited answer, please.

Comment: Thanks. Adding a subquery which contains UNION did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
select * from t
order by abs(inv_1), inv_1 desc
```

Result:

```
 CRN   INV_1   INV_2 
 ---- ------- ------ 
 GBP     100     100 
 GBP    -100    -100 
 GBP     400     400 
 GBP    -400    -400 
 GBP     500     500 
 GBP    -500    -500 
 GBP     700     700 
 GBP    -700    -700 
 GBP     800     800 
 GBP    -800    -800 
 GBP   10000   10000 
 GBP  -10000  -10000
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=b49fa4fb5e3010c75d3d26722207b001).

As you can see `UNION` is not needed to get the ordering you want.